# ASPX page - translation

Tags: asp.net

On my ASPX page I am using uiCulture="ru_RU" for Russian and uiCulture="fr_FR" for French. Both work fine, but uiCulture="zh_HANS", uiCulture="zh", or uiCulture="zh-HK" are not working for Chinese. Any idea?
I am running .NET 4.8

Thanks

App_GlobalResources Structure:

[image]

I dont have  App_LocalResources folder.

Answer (score 0):

There was a known issue with a few zh-based cultures in .NET/ASP.NET (however, not with the "zh_HANS" one):

["zh-Hans" vs "zh-CHS" and "zh-Hant" vs "zh-CHT"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b93c07b-93bd-465f-b48f-0fff544c06d8/quotzhhansquot-vs-quotzhchsquot-and-quotzhhantquot-vs-quotzhchtquot?forum=microsofttranslator)

Consider using the recommended ones with the correct names (aka rename the related folders and *.resx files' suffixes) "zh-Hans" and "zh-Hant" instead.

Comment: I am not sure where I would find these folders. ASP.NET is not the technology I am very familiar with.

Comment: Post/share your project Folders structures (especially, the App_GlobalResources and App_LocalResources folders).

Comment: Make sure that you specify the uiCulture in a proper case.

Comment: I did. Other languages like Russian, French, Japanese all work fine. It's just the Chinese that is not working.

Comment: Try to rename both: the resx file and the uiCulture property to "zh-Hant".

Comment: I think there is one detail I have missed to provide. This is not an application translation but rather MS ReportViewer toolbar.

Comment: Then, use my comments along with the hints from the suggested link